# Ubuntu Autopilot MAAS RAID Question

Tags: server, juju, raid, maas, openstack

I am about to start a small endeavour of setting up a small private test cloud and see one of the requirements being that each server requires 2 disks.

All of my servers are currently configured either with RAID1 or RAID1+0 depending on whether or not they have 2 or 4 physical disks.

Am I supposed to break down the raid and run without hardware raid in favor or one of the software storage applications with openstack?

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: I believe I found the answer I was looking for.

Comment: In regards to using SWIFT and found in the KILO openstack documentation.  I assume it holds true for most cases, CEPH, ZFS,etc?

"To get the most out of your hardware, it is essential that every disk used in OpenStack Object Storage is configured as a standalone, individual RAID 0 disk; in the case of 6 disks, you would have six RAID 0s or one JBOD. Some RAID controllers do not support JBOD or do not support battery backed cache with JBOD. "

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so it can help the next person? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself, and am answering it in hopes that it will help someone else.

In regards to using SWIFT and found in the KILO openstack documentation. I assume it holds true for most cases, CEPH, ZFS,etc? "To get the most out of your hardware, it is essential that every disk used in OpenStack Object Storage is configured as a standalone, individual RAID 0 disk; in the case of 6 disks, you would have six RAID 0s or one JBOD. Some RAID controllers do not support JBOD or do not support battery backed cache with JBOD. "